# Definitions of real reductive groups

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, rt.representation-theory

There are several definitions of real reductive groups, sometimes subtly inequivalent. The following come to my mind:

1. A closed subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ closed under conjugate transpose.
2. The set of real points $G(\mathbb R)$ of a real algebraic group such that $G(\mathbb C)$ is [reductive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group).
3. [Knapp's  definition](http://books.google.com/books?id=PAJmnm3DU1QC&lpg=PA454&ots=xeut6SQF7P&dq=reductive%20group%20knapp&pg=PA446#v=onepage&q=reductive&f=false) i.e. a Lie group $G$ with a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, a Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak g =\mathfrak k +\mathfrak p$, a maximal compact subgroup $K$ such that $G = K\cdot\mathrm{exp}(\mathfrak p)$ and such that every automorphism of $\mathfrak g$ of the form $\operatorname{Ad}(g)$, $g \in G$, is in $\operatorname{Int}(\mathfrak g^{\mathbb C})$.
4. [Harish-Chandra definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_class) i.e. 3. plus the condition that the connected component of the identity of a semisimple factor of $G$ has finite center.

Maybe there are others too. What are the relations between these different definitions?

Comment: It's more a question of the scope of the theory: for example, Harish-Chandra considered non-linear groups with compact center, which doesn't fall under 1 or 2. Knapp used a variant of 1 in "Beyond the introduction". Is there a particular reason that you need to use different definitions?

Comment: I corrected 2 and added a description of 4.

Comment: For #3, please define "Cartan decomposition" when the Lie algebra is not semisimple.  Note also that a torus violates #3 since its adjoint representation is trivial. These two points lead me to ask if Harish-Chandra considered $G$ whose Lie algebra is not semisimple. I thought he always worked with groups having semisimple Lie algebra (and then in inductive arguments with centralizers of tori would handle extra central stuff directly).  

Comment: Boyarsky, connectedness is one of the main issues for me.

Victor, it's mainly for efficient usage of the literature. Often the definition used in a paper is not explicitly stated.Personally, I use definition 3 because I like Knapp's book (actually 3 is from "Beyond an Introduction")

Comment: The exact definition is in the link. Essentially the torus can be decomposed in a compact part and a vector part too (this depends on the group, not only on the algebra)

A connected torus does not violate 3, because both Ad(G) and Int(**g**^C) are trivial

Comment: Andrea: sorry, I misread #3 near the end as saying "is of the form". Since connectedness is a main issue for you, I highly recommend focusing on condition #2 if possible. It is a wonderful thing to promote Lie algebra facts to global group facts for a connected real algebraic group (connected in the Zariski topology) even when the real points are disconnected. I once heard from Vogan that away from #2 (perhaps with connectedness in the algebraic sense), the main issue is to decide in what ways you want things to begin breaking down. 

Comment: Aspects of the relationship between #2 and #4 are addressed in section 24.C of Borel's book on linear algebraic groups. I have a vague memory (but cannot recall from where) that a Cartan involution can always be identified with conjugate transpose as in #1 (maybe this is due to Mostow?), and so I think #1 and #2 may be equivalent, at least modulo connectedness issues on which I'm less confident. 

Comment: I have also seen the definition: 5. Open subgroup of a group of the form #2. Maybe this is equivalent to #1

Comment: There is also a def in Wallach, Real reductive groups, which is a blend of your #2 and #3, I think, with an explicit map from G into R-points of a reductive linear algebraic group (I don't have it close by, so can't check the details). It's good to explicitly include Cartan decomposition, but I would take a pragmatic view: find which properties are needed for a particular application and quote the source which proves them, using its def. In practice, that means Wallach:) Older papers (and even books -- Vogan 1981?) liked to refer to Harish-Chandra's original papers, making it less accessible. 

Comment: Andrea, the connectedness tripped me up for relating #1 and #2.   The condition in #1 should be satisfied by identity component in #2, and so your condition #5 should indeed be equivalent to #1, but #2 with algebraically connected $G$ is probably the "best" situation in which to find oneself. As you know, connectedness is a persistent nuisance on the real-analytic side, whereas algebraically one has very nice connectedness results valid for any ground field (such as $\mathbf{R}$ even though it isn't algebraically closed). That's a reason why #2 with algebraically connected $G$ is "best". 

Comment: I'll leave this to specialists, but keep in mind that Elie Cartan would not have recognized the term *real reductive group*.   The notion of "reductive" for Lie or algebraic groups is more recent and also somewhat confusing.   The connotation of "completely reducible" inspired some papers by Hochschild and Mostow, where your definition 1 plays a role.  I'd tend to rely mostly on Vogan, Wallach, Knapp.

Comment: I think what's most useful here is to know the examples that tend to distinguish one of these from another. I'll contribute the easy one: the universal cover of $SL_n({\mathbb R})$, $n>2$, which does not sit inside a finite-dimensional matrix group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an old question, probably abandoned because its answer would require a short article (complete with references).   While I can't supply such an article, I can point to some of Borel's writings which involve a definition of "real reductive group".   In an old comment, Brian Conrad already referred to the added survey in Section 24C of Borel's second edition of *Linear Algebraic Groups* (GTM 126, Springer, 1991).  There is also a set of his lecture notes intended for a 2003 Chinese summer school, published (along with other lectures) as: Lie groups and linear algebraic groups. I. Complex and real groups.  *Lie groups and automorphic forms*, 1–49, AMS/IP Stud. Adv. Math., 37, Amer. Math. Soc.,
Providence, RI, 2006.  (See Sections 5-6.)

The definition he uses is in some ways the simplest and most natural, I think.  In the general framework of finite dimensional Lie algebras over an arbitrary field $K$ of characteristic 0, there are elementary definitions of *semisimple* and *reductive* Lie algebras.   When you take $K = \mathbb{R}$ and work in the classical framework of real Lie groups, it's then natural to define a *connected* Lie group $G$ to be *reductive* if its Lie algebra is.   Of course, the Lie algebra only sees local behavior, so one could leave it at that.  However, disconnected Lie groups come up immediately when Lie group theory is combined with linear algebraic groups in the study of representations, automorphic forms, etc.   So Borel adds in this case the extra requirement that $G$ have only finitely many connected components in the euclidean topology.

Where does this condition come from?  Starting with a *connected* linear algebraic group (scheme) $H$ over $\mathbb{R}$, the resulting group $G:= H(\mathbb{R})$ is a real Lie group but need not be connected.   An obvious example is the multiplicative group.   But a basic theorem states that this Lie group has only finitely many components in the euclidean topology.  The theorem comes, for instance, from Whitney's older work on real affine varieties but is also a consequence of a finiteness theorem in Galois cohomology proved in the work of Borel-Serre.   (I'm not sure what the best modern proof of the theorem is, but that's another question.)

Borel's notes were intended partly to prepare for Wallach's related lectures.  In any case, his approach is closely related to some of the other proposed definitions of real reductive group in the question.   But it strikes me as a more straightforward starting point.